# What Brand of Bicycle do I have?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I was thinking about restoring an old bike I bought years ago, but I don't know what kind it is, to the best I could see, here are the numbers that was on the bottom: MOTSX (the 0 is a maybe) then 45 402 these were slanted beside the MOSTX, then these below were under them.
Mod 702 (almost sure it was a 7) then the numbers under Mod 12  12      86 (and spaced like that).
I know it's a 26" boys, but I have never seem 2 small bars for top on a boys bike, plus they are not welded on frame under seat, but sit in special cups like a U that are welded on. I just wanted to make sure it was worth restoring. It looks to me like it's from the 50s or 60s. It has Schwinn on hand grips, but anyone could have switched those. Its in great shape, and won't take a lot to fix. Here a picture [image]Thanks Tom Barnes

Comment: Is there anything on the headtube? Many companies put their logo there, and even a silhouette may be helpful.

Comment: No Markings at all, if it had a Name Plate it has been removed, but there wasn't one riveted, there are no holes, one may have been glued? Someone had did a very bad paint job, I removed some of that paint, red is the original color.

Comment: @TomBarnes If you've identified it, please add that as an answer and then accept the answer, so other users can see your problem is solved.

Comment: Is teh black plasticky thing on the back original ?

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for bikes and I found one identical to this one: it was a VINTAGE 1959 MURRAY SEARS FLIGHTLINER, all it was missing is the little silver bar that goes above the front fender that clips into that little silver clip on the bottom of the headtube. Some may have had headlight tanks, the one I found  didn't. So it could be a 59-60?